# What is the best way to port a C++ library to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, compatibility, porting

I have a (header only) C++ library that I am looking to port to C#. It is a wrapper of the win api which I have made for a certain purpose. I want to port it to C# because I want to develop it further using C#. What is the most efficient (and easiest?) way to port it. Please note that I do not want something hectic because I don't want to spend more time porting the library than it took to make that library in the first place. So is there a way?

Comment: @Cassio was making my lib a header only a bad idea?

Comment: Not at all. I use headers in C++ as well. It's just a matter of transforming it into a DLL. Not a big deal, I guess.

Comment: It depends. Many high quality header-only libraries are that way because they heavily use templates, and so the code cannot be moved into a separate compilation unit (because it is generated at compile time). C# does not have an equivalent to templates (that I know of), so you would be out of luck.

Comment: @Mankarse No I did not use templates in my library (though i was about to). i just made it header only because most of the functions were inline.

Comment: why not using P/Invoke? it's very simple and it'll spare you the entire porting with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends very much on how big your lib is, how it is structured, how your memory allocation looks like, how much you made use of libs not available in C# (like the C++ std lib), how much C++ template programming you have used etc.

Different strategies may be

- try to port (parts of) it automatically by some code generator of your own
- do not port it to C#, instead use C++/CLI (something I did very successfully in the past)
- do it manually because the C++ concepts you have used so far don't map well to C#

"Header only" does not seem to make a real difference. In fact, things may technically get a little bit easier when you have just one C++ file for each class to be ported to one C# class file.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways I can think of.

1. Manual conversion to C# dll with possible code generation help of T4.
2. Change your c++ library to a managed dll so you can use it in your c# project.
3. Of course, you might use interop with your c++ library in your C# project. But in that case, I am not sure about purpose of your c++ library since you said it's a wrapper.

Since you already have c++ library that you can fully control, I would try to go with #2 first.